# Simple =IF Statement for ActiveSheet.Range.Value in Excel VBS triggers 1004 Runtime Error

Tags: excel, vba

Got the following code which DOES WORK as an Excel VBScript Macro:

```
Sub replace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheets(ws.Name).Activate

        Dim I
        For I = 5 To 20
            ActiveSheet.Range("T" & I).Value = "=AVERAGE(3)"
        Next I
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Obviously `=AVERAGE(3)` is not meant to be useful in any way, but to show that this code above **works**, and the following chunk does **not**:

```
Sub replace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheets(ws.Name).Activate

        Dim I
        For I = 5 To 20
            ActiveSheet.Range("T" & I).Value = "=IF(1=1;1;0)"
        Next I
     Next ws
End Sub
```

Actually there should be a way more complex formula where the `IF` is (which looks something like: `=IF(Q5<>0;IF(R5+S5>Q5;"ERROR";IF(R5="";S5/Q5;IF(Q5=R5;"Coord.";S5/(Q5-R5))));"N/A")`.

The thing is, I narrowed it down until I saw that even that trivial `=IF(1=1;1;0)` statement fails with the 1004 runtime error.

I don't think it's of importance to solve the issue, but the whole macro is just for the purpose of updating about 15 cells on each worksheet for about 31 worksheets. As I said, the first chunk works (with the `AVERAGE()` calculation) but the `=IF` does not work.

---

For the sake of completeness, this was the code that I wanted to have:

```
Sub updCells()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Sheets(ws.Name).Activate

        Dim I
        For I = 5 To 20
        ActiveSheet.Range("T" & I).Value = "=IF(Q" & I & "<>0,IF(R" & I & "+S" & I & ">Q" & I & ",""ERROR"",IF(R" & I & "="""",S" & I & "/Q" & I & ",IF(Q" & I & "=R" & I & ",""Coord."",S" & I & "/(Q" & I & "-R" & I & ")))),""N/A"")"

        Next I

     Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing the semi-colons with commas. (And using the Formula property rather than Value.) Oh, and you don't need the second loop.

Comment: Some Scandinavian language require the semi-colon in place of the comma. On my comma-requiring PC assigning the "=IF(1=1,1,0)" works fine even when assigning to Value but using semi-colons fails with error 1004. That surprised me because I was expecting Excel to be able to recognize a Value as Text. Apparently the leading = sign prevents that. Presuming that Kondado knows that his PC needs semi-colons, it would appear that his version of Excel reacts differently from mine when a formula is (wrongly) assigned to Value.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't call a procedure "Replace" because "Replace" is both a VBA and Excel Object and using the name can cause misunderstandings (= crashes). Before using a name, select it and press F1.

Comment: @Variatus It's not that Kondado's Excel reacts differently. It's that although some setups use semi-colon as separator in formulas written in worksheet, VBA is the same for everyone and you must use commas.

Comment: @Egan Wolf Interesting thought but I stumble over the fact that the code assigns a string to the cells's Value property. Can't help feeling that Excel is stumbling over its own feet here.

Comment: @EganWolf Just saw Egan Wolf's comment -- didn't know that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be reduced to the following as in addition to comments you don't need to activate sheets. See [how to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C271.1819).

This will also generally work for more complex formulae (such as your example) - Excel will work out the relative references.

```
Sub replace()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Range("T5:T20").Formula = "=IF(1=1,1,0)"
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks SJR and all others who have answered!!! The reason was using semi-colon instead of comma. I usually have to use semi-colon when typing the formula directly into Excel, but for some reason VBScript expects a simple comma. 

I also re-checked the system settings, as I had also been experimenting with converting between CSV and Excel for some data analysis, but even if I changed the setting and restarted Excel it still expected a comma in VBScript. I had also checked Excels own settings in this aspect. Anyway, you saved my day!! Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure. As an addendum you can use `FormulaLocal` instead and retain your semi-colons.